# Don't know why AJAX form data is sending null to the MVC controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring

I am sending a form data using AJAX and my Spring MVC controller is getting `null` value, but if I use **[Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/)** it will work fine.

**Here is my ajax call:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url:"http://localhost:8080/fivenet/mobile/api/login",
    crossDomain: true,
    data: JSON.stringify(formData),
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'text/html;charset=UTF-8',
    //contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
    beforeSend: function(xhr){
    },
    success: function(msg){
        console.log('sucess');
    },
 error: function(msg){}
```

**Here is my controller:**

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RequestMapping(value = "create-account", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody RespondMessage createAccount(
        @RequestParam(value = "data", required = true) String dataString,
        HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

    RespondMessage responsed = new RespondMessage();
    headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
    JSONObject data = new JSONObject(dataString);
 return responsed;
}
```

Comment: Does an error happen in the JavaScript console? Can you post exactly the parameters that you've used in POSTman, which worked?

Comment: Yes, it return 500 and when I run my spring in debug mode, the "String dataString" return null. The parameter looks like this {  
   "username":"xxx@gmail.com",
   "password":"12345"
}

Comment: How are you filling `formData`? Where's the code that initialize it?

Answer (score 1):

I have finally solved the problem. Its the way I serve my data.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "http://localhost:8080/fivenet/mobile/api/login",
    crossDomain: true,
    data: {"data": JSON.stringify(formData)},*** This is where the error is
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function(xhr){

    },
    success: function(msg){
        console.log('sucess');
    },
 error: function(msg){}
```

thanks all for your concerns

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var formData = {"username" : "username", "password" : "password"};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/fivenet/mobile/api/login",
    data: JSON.stringify(formData),
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
    beforeSend: function(xhr){
    },
    success: function(data){
        alert(data)
    },
    failure: function(errMsg) {
        alert(errMsg);
    },
    error: function(errMsg){
         alert(errMsg);
    }
```

Comment: When I tried @Chandra Kumar  method I get this :        XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/webservices/PodcastService.asmx/CreateMarkers. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: update your login web service url: `http://localhost:8080/fivenet/mobile/api/login`

Comment: ** I have same error ** POST http://localhost:8080/fivenet/mobile/api/login 500 ()

Comment: Request URL:http://localhost:8080/fivenet/mobile/api/login
Request Method:POST
Status Code:500 
Remote Address:[::1]:8080
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade